# dynamic javascript jquery graph chart by user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, charts

I'm converting a flash to html5 interactive or dynamic graphing like this where user will input the values on the input fields on the left, then it will show a graph result on the right. I'm looking for code resources where I can copy and change the variables or do some modification. Thank you so much!

http://www.learner.org/series/econusa/interactivelabs/graphing-lab_moose-synthesizer-co/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you need d3.js(a new javascript library)

Here are some examples http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock and https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery of graphs that you can use

**Edit:**
**No you can use d3 for that purpose**
check it out http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html 
and i am sure you can use simple jquery/javascript for the purpose of binding or retrieving values.
I am suggesting d3 because that's the best javascript library being used for the graphs and all.

Comment: Hi nsthethunderbolt, thanks for your reply! I saw bl.ocks.org earlier. My project requires an input field where user can type the data themselves and it will generate a result on the chart.

Comment: check the link in edit

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use almost any charting library for this purpose, most of them support dynamic data input. I made an example of this task using [amCharts.com](http://amcharts.com). You'll have a nice, scrollable XY chart: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/6Eb53/

Full source:

```
var chart;
AmCharts.ready(function() {
  // XY CHART
  chart = new AmCharts.AmXYChart();
  chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/";
  chart.marginRight = 0;
  chart.marginTop = 0;    
  chart.dataProvider = [];
  chart.autoMarginOffset = 0;
  // AXES
  // X
  var xAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
  xAxis.position = "bottom";
  xAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
  xAxis.autoGridCount = true;
  chart.addValueAxis(xAxis);

  // Y
  var yAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
  yAxis.position = "left";
  yAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
  yAxis.autoGridCount = true;
  chart.addValueAxis(yAxis);

  // graph
  var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph.yField = "value1";
  graph.xField = "x";
  chart.addGraph(graph);

  // CURSOR
  var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
  chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

  // SCROLLBAR
  var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
  chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

  // WRITE                                                
  chart.write("chartdiv");
});

function generateData(){
  var dataProvider = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
  {
    var value = Number(document.getElementById("input"+i).value);
    dataProvider.push({x:i, value1:value});
  }
  chart.dataProvider = dataProvider;
  chart.validateData();    
}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of amCharts library.